# SELECT data from two tables with same name

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

I've tried to find a way to select data from two tables within the same query as follows:

Suppose I have this as **table1**

```
id | item | qty
1  | 1bb1 | 12
2  | 1cc1 | 10
```

and as **table2**

```
id | item | qty
6  | 1bb1 | 12
7  | 1vv1 | 4
```

And I have an imported file which contains data **item** as `$sheetData[$i]['A']` from an excel sheet that I need to use it to find out if ***BOTH*** tables have this item or not.

My code as follows :

```
$query1="SELECT * FROM table1.item,table2.item WHERE item ='".$sheetData[$i]['A']."'";

$result1= mysql_query($query1);
if(mysql_num_rows($result1)>0){

echo "This Item Found in Both Tables";
echo $sheetData[$i]['A'];
echo "<br />";
}
else{
    echo "Item Could Not Be Found in both tables";
    echo $sheetData[$i]['A'];
}
```

Its basically I want to find out if the imported item found in both tables or not. I hope this makes sense for you!

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Try this -> SELECT A.* , B.* FROM table1 A, table2 B WHERE A.item=B.item AND A.item=' ".$sheetData[$i]['A']." '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler can't decide which item needs to compare. item from table1 or item from table2
So write query as:

```
SELECT A.* , B.* 
FROM table1 A, table2 B 
WHERE A.item  = B.item AND 
      A.item  = '".$sheetData[$i]['A']."'
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but the above code shows wrong output. It shows only "Item Could Not Be Found in both tables" two times.

Comment: Query is correct..but that means that item not available in your table

Comment: I agree your query is correct, there are no warnings or errors but I have double checked item in excel file, and in both tables. There should be one correct and one wrong.

Comment: just echo  $sheetData[$i]['A']; to check what it is returning

Comment: I've done echo $sheetData[$i]['A'] , and it outputs all data values from excel sheet whether its right or wrong. Query can't distinguish which value found in both tables or not. Although your code should work perfectly but..

Comment: I've tried closing down browsing, and did refresh whole page and now it works like a charm. Thanks Man +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
"SELECT t1.id, t1.item, t1.qty, t2.id id_2, t2.qty qty_2 FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.item = t1.item 
WHERE table1.item ='".$sheetData[$i]['A']."'"
```

> Try to avoid using **mysql**, it is deprecated now. **mysqli**/**PDO** instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I've tried using your code but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT 1 
  FROM table1
  WHERE item = ?

  UNION ALL

  SELECT DISTINCT 1  
  FROM table2
  WHERE item = ?) AS t
```

This will return 2 if the item exists in both tables, 1 if it exists in only 1 table and 0 if the item doesn't exists in any of the two tables.